# Retaining NaN values in rasterio read

Tags: qgis, rasterio

I am attempting to import a GeoTiff mask in which pixels of interest have the value 1, and off-target pixels are Nan using Rasterio. When viewed in QGIS and with `plt.show()`, off target pixels are shown correctly as "nodata" in QGIS and `[]` when viewed in `plt.show()`. However, when I read the band of the dataset, nan values within the boundaries of the image are converted to zeroes, whereas the added border pixels remain as nodata (shown as white in image below). Is there a way to retain the nan values when converted to an `np.array`?

```
file = r'[GeoTiff Path]'
# Convert file to raster
exg = rasterio.open(file, mode = 'r')

# Plotting raster and shapefile
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
show(exg, ax = ax)
plots.plot(ax = ax, facecolor = 'None', edgecolor = 'red')
plt.show()

# Assign raster values to numpy nd array
exg_array = exg.read(1)
show(exg_array)
```

[image: visualization of array]

Comment: what is the `dtype` of your raster?

Comment: @AmanBagrecha float32

Comment: What makes you think the NaN values aren't being retained?  I created a Float32 raster with np.nan, 1 and NoData areas, read it in using rasterio and inspected the array and can confirm that the NaNs are there.

Comment: @user2856 When I use the zonal_stats function in rasterstats on the binary GeoTiff for example, instead of returning a mean pixel value of 1, it appears that it includes the nodata pixels in the calculation as zeroes and as a result I get a decimal of some sort.

Comment: Yes, because your NaNs are not NoData, so looks like rasterstats counts them when generating the mean.  Don't use NaNs, set those areas to NoData.